# Endless Query/Loop in PHP?

Tags: php, html, mysql, sql

Hello I'm querying a database of names by the first letter of the last name. However when I excute the query and print the results, the first name prints over and over again when in reality theres more than one name to print out. here is what I have so far. the data passed in is a letter in which it supppose to gather all the last names with that beginning letter. what I'm I doing wrong that can cause this infinite loop?

```
function displayprofs()
{
print"<div>";
print "<p><a href = '$_SERVER[PHP_SELF]'>return to start</a>\n";
$abc=($_POST['abc']);
print"$abc";
$db = adodbConnect();
$query="Select * FROM Category WHERE Description LIKE '$abc%'";
$result=$db->Execute($query);
$row=$result->FetchRow();
while($row)
    {

      $name= $row['Description'];
      print "<form method='post' enctype='multipart/form-data' action='$_SERVER[PHP_SELF]'>\n";
      print"<input type='hidden' name='profy' value='$name'>";
      print"<p>$name<input type='submit' name='add' value ='Submit'/></p>\n";                                                   //submit button
      print"</form>\n";
      //break;
    } 
print"</div>";  
}
```

Comment: sorry it was a autocorrect error

Comment: `while($row=$result->FetchRow())` instead of `while($row)` and remove `$row=$result->FetchRow()`

Answer (score 4):

You fetch `$row` once and then start `while` loop with its condition always true. Missing `$row=$result->FetchRow();` inside the `while` block.

Comment: Hi I replaced it and it still give me the infinite loop, it crashes my browser too.

Answer (score 4):

Replace `while($row)` with `while($row=$result->FetchRow())`

and remove `$row=$result->FetchRow();` you've written before starting `while`

Answer (score 0):

Since you have `while($row)` you will iterate over the same row over and over again. Change to `while($row=$result->FetchRow())` instead and remove the previous fetch or keep as is and put `$row=$result->FetchRow();` in the end of the while block.

Solution 1:

```
    while($row=$result->FetchRow())
    {

      $name= $row['Description'];
      print "<form method='post' enctype='multipart/form-data' action='$_SERVER[PHP_SELF]'>\n";
      print"<input type='hidden' name='profy' value='$name'>";
      print"<p>$name<input type='submit' name='add' value ='Submit'/></p>\n";                                                   //submit button
      print"</form>\n";
    }
```

Solution 2:

```
    $row=$result->FetchRow();
    while($row)
    {
      $name= $row['Description'];
      print "<form method='post' enctype='multipart/form-data' action='$_SERVER[PHP_SELF]'>\n";
      print"<input type='hidden' name='profy' value='$name'>";
      print"<p>$name<input type='submit' name='add' value ='Submit'/></p>\n";                                                      //submit button
      print"</form>\n";
      $row=$result->FetchRow();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

By now, you know the `while($row)` bit is probably a mistake. Just to avoid you having to post a second question in a minute: This isn't the best of ideas:

```
print "<form method='post' enctype='multipart/form-data' action='$_SERVER[PHP_SELF]'>\n";
```

Perhaps consider writing this as *either*:

```
print "<form method='post' enctype='multipart/form-data' action='{$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']}'>\n";
```

*or*:

```
print "<form method='post' enctype='multipart/form-data' action='".$_SERVER[PHP_SELF]."'>\n";
```